# When a non-existing Option is set as defaultValue under the Select of ant.d, the key will be shown

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have ant.design Select like

```
<Form.Item
 name="select_list_group"
 label="Select Group">
  <Select
   showSearch
   optionLabelProp="children"
   allowClear={true}
   notFoundContent={null}
 >
  <Option key="1" value="1" >Group One</Option>
  <Option key="2" value="2" >Group Two</Option>
  <Option key="4" value="4" >Group Four</Option>
 </Select>
</Form.Item>
```

Then I set initialValues to non-existing value like "3".

```
<Form
 ref={this.formFourFormRef}
 onFinish={onFinish}
 initialValues={{select_list_group: "3"}}
>
```

It shows 3. 
like

[image]

When a non-existing value is set as initialValues, I want it to be emptied.

Comment: I improved formatting.

Comment: Can anyone reopen it?